# Passing state through navigation React Native/Expo

Tags: react-native, navigation, state, expo, react-props

In my react native app I have one fetch request that is grabbing a JSON from a postgres server. This fetch sets the state and is passed down through the children of the HomeScreen to maintain state through out the components.

In my UserScreen and OverviewScreen I require access to the same state state that is being refreshed by a child of HomeScreen. How do I pass this prop through the navigation to set the state for both the OverviewScreen and UserScreen?

Navigator is set up in its own file as so. Should I set up my fetch request through this page and pass the props to each tab?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import TabBarIcon from '../components/TabBarIcon';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import OverviewScreen from '../screens/OverviewScreen';
import AchievementsScreen from '../screens/AchievementsScreen';
import UserScreen from '../screens/UserScreen';

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
});

HomeStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={
        Platform.OS === 'ios'
          ? `ios-checkbox${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`
          : 'md-checkbox'
      }
    />
  ),
};

const OverviewStack = createStackNavigator({
  Overview: OverviewScreen,
});

OverviewStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Overview',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-trending-up' : 'md-trending-up'}
    />
  ),
};

const AchievementsStack = createStackNavigator({
  Achievements: AchievementsScreen,
});

AchievementsStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Achievments',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-star' : 'md-star'}
    />
  ),
};

const UserStack = createStackNavigator({
  User: UserScreen,
});

UserStack.navigationOptions = {
  tabBarLabel: 'Settings',
  tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
    <TabBarIcon
      focused={focused}
      name={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'ios-information-circle-outline' : 'md-information-circle-outline'}
    />
  ),
};

export default createBottomTabNavigator({
  HomeStack,
  OverviewStack,
  AchievementsStack,
  UserStack,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass parameters from one screen to other screens when navigating. 
You can fetch data in `HomeScreen` and pass them. Read more about how to do that here in the [official docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html)

From the docs:

There are two pieces to this:

Pass params to a route by putting them in an object as a second parameter to the `navigation.navigate` function: `this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteName', { /* params go here */ })`

Read the params in your screen component: `this.props.navigation.getParam(paramName, defaultValue).`